# How to force other angular components to refresh and update the view?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am working on an Angular +2 app where we provide the user an 'update your profile' page. The user is permitted to update their username from, say, "JSmith to "JDoe". We have a separate menu component in the upper right that displays some basic user data---username, email, etc.

Problem: After the user updates their username I want the save method to trigger updates to the menu component as well so that the displayed info--username,etc.--gets updated as well.

Question: what is the technique to execute changes to specific components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to notify other components of changes to data you can use a event model. Basically you create a singleton service that is injected into your components. This service has a `Subject` field which can be used to broadcast changes as well as subscribe to that broadcast.

**userMenu.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserStateService } from './userState.service';

export class UserMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly userStateService: UserStateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userStateService.userChanged
            .asObservable()
            .subcribe(userInfo => {/* do something */});
    }
}
```

**userInput.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserStateService } from './userState.service';

export class UserInputComponent {
    userData: any;
    constructor(private readonly userStateService: UserStateService) { }

    onSave() {
        this.userStateService.userChanged.next(this.userData);
    }
}
```

**userState.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserStateService {
    userChanged = new Subject();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I appreciate the level of detail in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a service and exposing an `Observable<UserInfo>` then all of your components such as menu, toolbar and ... subscribing to this service to get UserInfo, then when a user info changes you only need to `next` that observable, everything will be updated automagically

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that has the username , email , etc properties as public static properties. So you can update the static variables in one component and read them in another and it will change instantly. (the 2 components will work on the same properties stored in the service , one component will change those properties and the other will be reading directly from them).